# Generar etiquetas con zk framework desde java

Tags: java, sql-server-2014, zk

espero esten de lo mejor, el problema que tengo es que quiero generar un menu en zk framework, pero quiero generar los datos desde java. El problema es que no se si lo que formule me sirva. Necesito ayuda, aparte que no se como hacer que java cree las etiquetas con forme a los datos que saca de la base de datos.
Necesito ayuda para poder agarrar los datos que tome, y poder generar el menu.

```
//// esta clase extraera y devolvera los datos que agarre de la base.
public class MenuOption {
private int id_memu;
private int id_padre;
private int id_orden;
private String nombre_menu;
private String url_img;
private String url_pag;





public MenuOption(int padre, int orden, String nombre, String img,String pag) {

    this.id_padre = padre;
    this.id_orden = orden;
    this.nombre_menu = nombre;
    this.url_img = img;
    this.url_pag = pag;

}


public int getId_memu() {
    return id_memu;
}

public void setId_memu(int id_memu) {
    this.id_memu = id_memu;
}

public int getId_padre() {
    return id_padre;
}

public void setId_padre(int id_padre) {
    this.id_padre = id_padre;
}

public int getId_orden() {
    return id_orden;
}

public void setId_orden(int id_orden) {
    this.id_orden = id_orden;
}

public String getNombre_menu() {
    return nombre_menu;
}

public void setNombre_menu(String nombre_menu) {
    this.nombre_menu = nombre_menu;
}

public String getUrl_img() {
    return url_img;
}

public void setUrl_img(String url_img) {
    this.url_img = url_img;
}

public String getUrl_pag() {
    return url_pag;
}

public void setUrl_pag(String url_pag) {
    this.url_pag = url_pag;
}



 }
```

/// otra clase

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.abraham.conexionSQL.conexion;;

public class DatosSql {

      private PreparedStatement pst;
      private ResultSet rst;
      private conexion con = new conexion();
      public ArrayList<MenuOption> GetConsultaMenu(String app) throws SQLException{
           Connection conn = con.getConexion();
           String query = "SELECT ID_OPCION_MENU,NIVEL,ORDEN,NOMBRE_MENU,URL_IMG,URL_PAG FROM MENU WHERE ID_APP ='"+app+"'";
           ArrayList<MenuOption> almacenes = new ArrayList<MenuOption>();
           pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
           rst = pst.executeQuery();
           rst.moveToCurrentRow();
           while (!rst.isAfterLast()){
              MenuOption almacenesCon = cursorToContact(rst);
              almacenes.add(almacenesCon);
              rst.moveToCurrentRow();
           }
           rst.close();
           return almacenes;
     }

     private MenuOption cursorToContact(ResultSet cursor) throws SQLException {
    MenuOption alma1 = new MenuOption(
            cursor.getInt(1),
            cursor.getInt(2),
            cursor.getString(3),
            cursor.getString(4),
            cursor.getString(5));
       alma1.setId_memu(cursor.getInt(0));

       return alma1;
  }
}
```

//// y la clase que jalaria los datos

```
   import java.awt.Cursor;
   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import java.sql.SQLException;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.sql.SQLData;

   import com.abraham.conexionSQL.conexion;
       public class Menu {
         private ArrayList<MenuOption> opciones;
         private DatosSql datos;
         private conexion con = new conexion();
public void GenerarMenu(String app) throws SQLException{
    Connection conn = con.getConexion();
    opciones = datos.GetConsultaMenu(app);

    ArrayList<String> nombres = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (MenuOption opcionesMenu : opciones) {
        nombres.add(opcionesMenu.getNombre_menu());

      }
   }

  }
```

Comment: Hola he actualizado las etiquetas para mejorar la aparicion de resultados relacionados en el panel de la derecha

Answer (score 0):

No se si esta trabajando con el patrón MVC, pero si es así, no veo cual es tu controlador, ya que el generar las etiquetas desde código Java debe ser desde tu controlador, la cual hereda todo de la clase GenericForwardComposer en dado caso uses esa, si es de esta manera, en tu código html solo debes tener un contenedor, puede ser una etiqueta menubar y dentro una menu, la cual la declaras en tu controlador, para que esta sea el padre de cada ítem de menú que deseas crear.

De esta manera dentro de tu código java, donde tengas el bucle que lleva tus datos de menú dinámico, solo vas creando objetos del tipo Menuitem, por ejemplo:

```
Menuitem itmenu = new Menuitem();
```

A los cuales le podes ir agregando los atributos que gustes, y solo le indicas su etiqueta padre que habías declarado como tipo Menu, creo que esto es lo que deseas hacer? .

Comment: Hola, eso más o menos lo capte y lo pude solucionar de la siguiente forma, por que mi idea es generar un menu de árbol, e igual pude hacer algo pero no eh podido editarlo del todo, no se como ponerle una url a cada item.